# Unable to manually compile and use user-defined namespaces in c#

Tags: c#, command-line, namespaces

I had just started learning C# programming language and I'm trying to run code manually(using **command line**) and on **Visual Studio** both. But now I'm stuck on "*namespaces*". I had made two files, one containing user-defined namespace and another file will access that namespace features. I succeeded in running this code on Visual Studio but unable to run manually. The file containing only namespace is not compiling and giving error that "***it does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point***". The two files are in the same folder. See the code below:

```
//file "Check1.cs"
namespace Ankur{
    public class Check1{
       public string a = "Hello world!";
    }
}


//file "Checkit.cs"
using System;
using Ankur;
class Checkit{
    static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine(Check1.a);
    }
}
```

How Visual Studio is running that code and what should I do to successfully run this code manually?

Comment: What is the command you used to compile?

Comment: Please show your attempt to "run it manually" - what actual command line did you enter?

Comment: You don't compile each file separately. You should pass all source code files to csc that are meant to be compiled together.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : what command to be given?

Comment: `csc Check1.cs Checkit.cs`

Comment: This is a different error: A syntax error, unrelated to this question which is about compiling. a is not static, you can't access it without an instance. If you don't know what this means, I think you should read up on C# and object-oriented programming in general before asking more.

Comment: sorry @GeorgeT , I got the point so deleted my comment..